# Implementing custom OAuth token endpoint for spring

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, token

I want to use Spring security and protect resources access using access tokens and I need to support issuing access tokens based on already issued Facebook and Google tokens form my mobile app. My service shall issue new service specific tokens and support refresh tokens.

Are there any examples of this using Spring security OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Found this one that really rocks
[OpenContextApps](https://github.com/OpenConextApps/apis)